# How do we know PA is incomparable with PRA + $\epsilon_0$?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, peano-axioms, ordinal-analysis

[Gödel 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem) says that no subtheory of PA can prove Con$_{PA}$, and even though most natural theories $T$ extending PA can prove Con$_{PA}$, this is relatively uninteresting since anyone doubting the consistency of PA would certainly mistrust $T$. If all "natural" theories were totally ordered that would be the end of it, but the significance of [Gentzen's consistency proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) is that it establishes Con$_{PA}$ from an incomparable system PRA + $\epsilon_0$, which one can conceivably believe in without already trusting PA in the first place.

To see that PRA + $\epsilon_0 \not\subseteq$ PA, is straightforward, since the latter proves induction up to $\epsilon_0$, Con$_{PA}$, and Goodstein's theorem, none of which PA can prove (if its consistent).

But showing PA $\not\subseteq$ PRA + $\epsilon_0$ has me scratching my head. Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof#Relation_to_Hilbert's_program_and_G%C3%B6del's_theorem) the latter "does not prove ordinary mathematical induction for all formulae" which PA does by definition. But no justification or reference is given there, and it's not obvious to me (or my thesis advisor) how to prove this claim (assuming a metatheory that can prove its consistency and perhaps more).

I'm also interested if there are any other (ideally "natural") statements that PA proves but PRA + $\epsilon_0$ does not. I can think of very few that PA proves but PRA alone doesn't, and it [seems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165428/are-there-natural-small-and-total-recursive-functions-that-are-not-primitive-r/165443#165443) these will necessarily involve fast-growing functions like Ackermann. So e.g. the totality of Ackermann is the classic example of something PA can prove but not PRA, but if I'm not mistaken that statement can also be shown by induction up to $\omega^\omega$ so it doesn't resolve this question. To summarize:

> How do we rigorously show that PRA + $\epsilon_0$ does not prove PA's induction schema? Are there any other statements that have this property, and why?

Comment: What do you mean by $\epsilon_0$? A schema of transfinite induction of length $\epsilon_0$? The statement that a certain linear order (of type $\epsilon_0$ is well-founded? Something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is far from optimal, but it is fun:

*Note that PRA isn't literally in the same language as PA, so by "PRA" we really mean "an appropriate rephrasing of PRA in the language of PA." This isn't an issue in this context, but it's worth pointing out.*

Let's shift attention. The theory $I\Sigma_1$ consists of basic arithmetic (the ordered semiring axioms) and induction for $\Sigma_1$-formulas. It's not hard to check that $I\Sigma_1$ contains PRA ($I\Sigma_1$ proves "every primitive recursive function is total").

So it's enough to show that "$I\Sigma_1+\epsilon_0$" doesn't contain PA. Why is $I\Sigma_1$ a better theory to use here? Well, it turns out that $I\Sigma_1$ is finitely axiomatizable. Hence $I\Sigma_1+\epsilon_0$ is also finitely axiomatizable.

- The key here: induction for bounded-complexity formulas along $\epsilon_0$ *looks* like a scheme, but can be captured by a single sentence via the appropriate truth-predicate. (Of course that breaks down if we drop "bounded" ...)

... So what? Well, this is the neat bit: there is a beautiful model-theoretic proof of the incompleteness of PA (due to Kripke, [written up by Putnam](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1027953483)) which has as a corollary that *no finitely axiomatizable extension of PA in the language of PA is consistent* (the key aspect of PA being that it proves the consistency of each of its finite subtheories). Bam, we're done.

Comment: Wow, not the strategy I was expecting, and I learned a lot from that! Do you have justification/reference for why $I\Sigma_1$ is finitely axiomatizable? I'm quite ignorant about that.

Comment: I assume you mean that you use partial truth predicates, i.e. a $\Sigma_2$ formula $Tr_1$ such that $Tr_1(\ulcorner \phi(x) \urcorner) \leftrightarrow \phi(x)$ is provable for (the Gödel number of) any $\Sigma_1$ formula $\phi$. But it's not clear to me how to use that to get a finite axiomatization.

Comment: So I'm scrutinizing pp. 350-360 of _Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic_. It'll take me some time to digest but p. 353 says "$I\Delta_0$ is not finitely axiomatizable". Which makes me skeptical of your claim, or at least if would be interesting if true.

Comment: @MorganSinclaire Remember that $\Delta$ and $\Sigma$ are *very* different - roughly, the set of $\Sigma_n$ formulas is computable but the set of $\Delta_n$ formulas *isn't* (remember that $\Delta_n$ isn't a syntactic condition, it's a semantic one - it asserts equivalence with both a $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ formula). For our purposes, remember that there is a "universal" $\Sigma_1$ formula, and we can use this to get a single sentence asserting that all instances of $\Sigma_1$-induction hold. (I'm a bit busy at the moment, details in a bit.)

Comment: (Incidentally, all we in fact need is that $I\Sigma_1$ is *contained in* a finitely axiomatizable theory, so we just need to focus on getting every instance of $\Sigma_1$-induction - it doesn't matter if we overshoot.)

Comment: Ah, p. 78 does show that $I\Sigma_n$ is finitely axiomatizable for n > 0, and it uses partial truth predicates as you said.

Comment: @NoahSchweber 1) Why does $I\Sigma_1$ contains PRA mean $I\Sigma_1$ proves "every primitive recursive function is total"? 2) Why can $I\Sigma_1$ be finitely axiomatized (or should I start a question for this)? 3) I just read the beautiful Kripke proof (thank you for that!), but where is it used that PA proves the consistency of each of its finite sub-theories?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also, can we easily strengthen the theorem "PA is not finitely axiomatized" to "no consistent extension of PA can be finitely axiomatized"?

Comment: @Jori Re: your second question, yes (see above: "no finitely axiomatizable extension of PA in the language of PA is consistent" - this is mentioned at the end of the Putnam paper). Re: your first question, I'll need to reread the paper again - it's possible I made a mistake there.

Comment: @NoahSchweber With regards to the finite axiomatizability of PA, I meant that suppose we know that PA is not finitely axiomatized (say by Feferman's proof, as in Takeuti), can we also easily get the stronger "no consistent extension of PA can be finitely axiomatized" (as in the Putnam paper). Also, why does $I\Sigma_1$ contains PRA mean $I\Sigma_1$ proves "every primitive recursive function is total"? Do you have a reference for the later claim, or is it easy to see?

Comment: To clarify: I meant a reference that $I\Sigma_1$ proves all primitive recursive functions total.