# Kripke's proof of the incompleteness of PA

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness, nonstandard-models

In [Hillary Putnam's writeup on Kripke's beautiful incompleteness proof of PA](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1027953483), which I learned about from Noah Schweber's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130538/how-do-we-know-pa-is-incomparable-with-pra-epsilon-0), I can convince myself that (see the top of p.56) "$s$ fulfills $A$" is primitive recursive in $s$, but why is $\text{Fulfills}(s, A_n)$ a primitive recursive relation in $s$ and $n$? Here $A_n$ is a fixed enumerable recursive sequence of formulas.

(I hope you find this question Noah :) )

Comment: *(It did find me!)* If I recall correctly, the point is that we basically only need an **explicitly bounded** search to determine whether $Fulfills(s,A_n)$ holds. Keep in mind that for every Turing machine $\Phi$ and every primitive recursive function $f$, the function sending $n$ to $\Phi(n)$ if $\Phi(n)$ halts in at most $f(n)$ stages and sending $n$ to $0$ otherwise (say) is itself primitive recursive, so you just need to check that the bound on that search is in fact appropriately small. But I don't have time at the moment to double-check this, so this is an answer as opposed to a comment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You mean _"this is a comment as opposed to an answer"_? What if I offer you 50 bounty points :) ? By the way, thanks again for all your help. I've learned A LOT from your many answers over the past months. Here and on MO. So, thank-you for that!