# Concrete examples of statements not provable in PRA + $\epsilon_0$-induction that are provable in PA?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, peano-axioms

It is well-known that $\mathbf{PRA}$ plus $\epsilon_0$-induction on bounded formulas cannot prove all $\mathbf{PA}$ theorems ([essentially because $I\Sigma_1$ plus $\epsilon_0$-induction on bounded formulas is finitely axiomatizable while the latter isn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130538/how-do-we-know-pa-is-incomparable-with-pra-epsilon-0)). Are there any concrete examples known (preferable "natural")?

(I have cross-posted this [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366871/concrete-examples-of-statements-not-provable-in-pra-epsilon-0-induction-tha))

Comment: [Emil Jeřábek answered this over at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/368134/151697).